# Building string in Excel VBA to output to Word is returning "False" instead of string

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, office-2013

I'm trying to build a string in Excel VBA that will then be output to a Word file.
The basic strings I'm creating are working fine, but these complex strings are coming in to Word as "False" so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm working with Excel / Word 2013.

Example excel file and word template here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5611192/Sales%20Package%20-%20Test%20for%20Word%20Proposal.xlsm

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5611192/Proposal.docx

The strings that aren't working are built with the following loop:

```
With Sheet1
    For RowCnt = Firstrow To Lastrow
        If .Cells(RowCnt, 15).Value = "x" And .Cells(RowCnt, 13).Value = "" Then
            strProducts = strProducts & .Cells(RowCnt, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(RowCnt, 8).Value & Chr(11)
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCnt, 15).Value = "x" And Cells(RowCnt, 13).Value = "1" Then
            strOptions1 = strOptions1 & .Cells(RowCnt, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(RowCnt, 8).Value & Chr(11)
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCnt, 15).Value = "x" And .Cells(RowCnt, 13).Value = "2" Then
            strOptions2 = strOptions2 & .Cells(RowCnt, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(RowCnt, 8).Value & Chr(11)
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCnt, 15).Value = "x" And .Cells(RowCnt, 13).Value = "3" Then
            strOptions3 = strOptions3 & .Cells(RowCnt, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(RowCnt, 8).Value & Chr(11)
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCnt, 15).Value = "x" And .Cells(RowCnt, 13).Value = "4" Then
            strOptions4 = strOptions4 & .Cells(RowCnt, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(RowCnt, 8).Value & Chr(11)
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCnt, 15).Value = "x" And .Cells(RowCnt, 13).Value = "5" Then
            strOptions5 = strOptions5 & .Cells(RowCnt, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(RowCnt, 8).Value & Chr(11)
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCnt, 15).Value = "x" And .Cells(RowCnt, 13).Value = "6" Then
            strOptions6 = strOptions6 & .Cells(RowCnt, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(RowCnt, 8).Value & Chr(11)
        End If
    Next RowCnt
End With

strProducts = strProducts & Chr(11) & Range("A47").Font.Bold = True & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strPrice
strOptions1 = strOptions1 & Chr(11) & Range("A47").Font.Bold = True & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strOption1Price
strOptions2 = strOptions2 & Chr(11) & Range("A47").Font.Bold = True & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strOption2Price
strOptions3 = strOptions3 & Chr(11) & Range("A47").Font.Bold = True & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strOption3Price
strOptions4 = strOptions4 & Chr(11) & Range("A47").Font.Bold = True & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strOption4Price
strOptions5 = strOptions5 & Chr(11) & Range("A47").Font.Bold = True & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strOption5Price
strOptions6 = strOptions6 & Chr(11) & Range("A47").Font.Bold = True & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strOption6Price
```

Comment: Are you giving away any particularly sensitive information in that excel sheet? Or the word template?

Comment: No, I've sanitized the documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution

Taking the example of the first string:

```
strProducts = strProducts & Chr(11) & Range("A47").Font.Bold = True & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strPrice
```

This part is your issue:

```
Range("A47").Font.Bold = True
```

Change this to:

```
Iif(Range("A47").Font.Bold = True,True,False)
```

Similarly for the other strings.

### The final code

Based on feedback from your comments your code should look like this:

```
strProducts = strProducts & Chr(11) & Range("A47").Value & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strPrice
Range("A47").Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: That particular line of code is applying Bold format to the data in A47... it's not evaluating anything

Comment: Then why are you appending it to the string between the Chr(11) characters? Remove it from the string then. I tested a similar line of code and it also evaluates to False because of this part

Comment: There's text in cell A47 that I want to append to the string, and I want that text to be formatted as Bold... is there a different method for accomplishing this?

Comment: To append the text simply replace the part with `Range("A47").Value`. In a separate line place your code `Range("A47").Font.Bold = True`. Alternatively you can place the latter part in the same line at the end but separated by a `:` - this means that this is a separate operation (but the interpreter with process both operations in the same go)

Comment: You're right... that line is what was screwing up the code... however, when I changed the code to this: 'Range("A47").Font.Bold = True
        
        strProducts = strProducts & Chr(11) & Range("A47") & Chr(11) & "Purchase, including installation:                   " & strPrice
 ... ' then the text is not bolded

Comment: Hmm... that changes the text in the Cell to bold, but not in the string... looks like I can't put formatting directly into the string, but I have to format it after the fact... I'll have to find another method to do what I'm look for... however you definitely fixed my original issue, thanks!